# Adding numbers in Flash AS 2.0

Tags: flash

I have searched quite a bit before posting this, weeks actually.

Must be Action Script 2.0

I want to have a text box where a user can enter a number and send it to a text box, then if they enter another number it will add it to the number already in the text box. So if I type in 10 it will show 10 in the output textbox, then if I type 10 and hit enter again it will display 20. Once it reaches a set number it starts over from 0 again.

Comment: After more than 10 years using Flash I didn't think I'd write this, but here goes: stop using Flash. [Adobe is dropping support for the plugin in 2020](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/). You can [use an input text in html/js](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp). 1. create the text field and variable for your total sum. 2. listen for for the [Enter key](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp), 3. parse the input text and add to total and if the total is greater then your set number, reset your total sum variable.

Comment: This project is only needed short term and is a very large scale project and will need to be done in AS2, somehow. It's a completed project that has taken months. It was a go to solution for the next two years. Taking the time to do it again using something else is not an option.

Comment: depending on your setup you'll have a Dynamic Text Field created in the IDE and set to type Input (otherwise just create one from code). The [TextField class has an onChanged event](http://demo.ligams.free.fr/AS2LR/TextField.html#event:onChanged) whenever something's changed or you can listen for the Enter key and check if the text field is focused. That should allow you to get the text that has been typed. You can then, as I mentioned above, parse the integer value of the text, add to your total and evaluate the if condition against the threshold set number.